# Connecting two points with curved lines (s-ish curve) in R

Tags: r, plot, taxonomy

Suppose I would like to produce a kind of tree structure like the one below:

```
plot(0, type="n",xlim=c(0, 5), ylim=c(-3, 8), axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="", main="")
points(1, 2.5)
points(3, 5)
points(3, 0)
lines(c(1, 3), c(2.5, 5))
lines(c(1, 3), c(2.5, 0))
text(1, 2.5, adj=1, label="Parent   ")
text(3, 5, adj=0, label="   Child 1")
text(3, 0, adj=0, label="   Child 2")
```

[image]

I wonder if there is a way in `R` where we can produce curved lines that resemble varying degrees of a S-curve like the ones below. Crucially it would be great if it would be possible to create such lines without resorting to `ggplot`.

[image]

**EDIT removed and made into an answer**

Comment: That's a nice edit! I might steal this in fact. You should make your edit an answer and accept it yourself - certainly worthy of an upvote or 3.

Comment: @thelatemail: Thanks for the suggestion. I added my answer and included a slightly more elaborated example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following @thelatemail's suggestion, I decided to make my edit into an answer. My solution is based on @thelatemail's answer.

I wrote a small function to draw curves, which makes use of the logistic function:

```
#Create the function
curveMaker <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2, ...){
    curve( plogis( x, scale = 0.08, loc = (x1 + x2) /2 ) * (y2-y1) + y1, 
                   x1, x2, add = TRUE, ...)
}
```

A working example is below. In this example, I want to create a plot for a taxonomy with 3 levels: `parent` --> `2 children` -- > `20 grandchildren`. One child has 12 grandchildren, and the other child has 8 children.

```
#Prepare data:
parent <- c(1, 16)
children <- cbind(2, c(8, 28))
grandchildren <- cbind(3, (1:20)*2-1)
labels <- c("Parent ", paste("Child ", 1:2), paste(" Grandchild", 1:20) )


#Make a blank plot canvas
plot(0, type="n", ann = FALSE, xlim = c( 0.5, 3.5 ), ylim = c( 0.5, 39.5 ), axes = FALSE )

#Plot curves
#Parent and children
invisible( mapply( curveMaker, 
                   x1 = parent[ 1 ], 
                   y1 = parent[ 2 ], 
                   x2 = children[ , 1 ], 
                   y2 = children[ , 2 ], 
                   col = gray( 0.6, alpha = 0.6 ), lwd = 1.5 ) )

#Children and grandchildren
invisible( mapply( curveMaker, 
                   x1 = children[ 1, 1 ], 
                   y1 = children[ 1, 2 ], 
                   x2 = grandchildren[ 1:8 , 1 ], 
                   y2 = grandchildren[ 1:8, 2 ], 
                   col = gray( 0.6, alpha = 0.6 ), lwd = 1.5 ) ) 
invisible( mapply( curveMaker, 
                   x1 = children[ 2, 1 ], 
                   y1 = children[ 2, 2 ], 
                   x2 = grandchildren[ 9:20 , 1 ], 
                   y2 = grandchildren[ 9:20, 2 ], 
                   col = gray( 0.6, alpha = 0.6 ), lwd = 1.5 ) )
#Plot text
text( x = c(parent[1], children[,1], grandchildren[,1]), 
      y = c(parent[2], children[,2], grandchildren[,2]),
      labels = labels,
      pos = rep(c(2, 4), c(3, 20) ) ) 

#Plot points
points( x = c(parent[1], children[,1], grandchildren[,1]),
        y = c(parent[2], children[,2], grandchildren[,2]), 
        pch = 21, bg = "white", col="#3182bd", lwd=2.5, cex=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a sigmoid curve, e.g.:

```
f <- function(x,s) s/(1 + exp(-x))
curve(f(x,s=1),xlim=c(-4,4))
curve(f(x,s=0.9),xlim=c(-4,4),add=TRUE)
curve(f(x,s=0.8),xlim=c(-4,4),add=TRUE)
curve(f(x,s=0.7),xlim=c(-4,4),add=TRUE)
```

Result:

[image]

You can start to adapt this, e.g. here's a clunky bit of code:

```
plot(NA,type="n",ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE,xlim=c(-6,6),ylim=c(0,1))
curve(f(x,s=1),xlim=c(-4,4),add=TRUE)
curve(f(x,s=0.8),xlim=c(-4,4),add=TRUE)
curve(f(x,s=0.6),xlim=c(-4,4),add=TRUE)
text(
   c(-4,rep(4,3)),
   c(0,f(c(4),c(1,0.8,0.6))),
   labels=c("Parent","Kid 1","Kid 2","Kid 3"), 
   pos=c(2,4,4,4)
)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to specify not only the end point coordinates but also the starting point coordinates of the curve? Suppose that instead starting from `x = 0` & `y = 0`, I would like to start at `x = 1` & `y = 5` (and end at `x = 5` & `y = 20`).

Comment: @Alex - I think you need something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function as the curve function

Answer (score 4):

I think Paul Murrell has a document illustrating similar diagrams in grid. Here's a basic example,

[image]

```
library(grid)

labelGrob <- function(x,y,label, ...){
  t <- textGrob(x,y,label=label)
  w <- convertWidth(1.5*grobWidth(t), "npc", valueOnly = TRUE)
  h <- convertHeight(1.5*grobHeight(t), "npc", valueOnly = TRUE)
  gTree(cl = "label", west = unit(x-0.5*w, "npc"), 
        east = unit(x+0.5*w, "npc"),
        children=gList(t, roundrectGrob(x=x, y=y, gp=gpar(fill=NA),
                                        width=w, height=h)))

}

xDetails.label <- function(x, theta){
  if(theta == 180) return(x$west[1]) else
    if(theta == 0) return(x$east[1]) else
  xDetails(x$children[[1]], theta) 
}

yDetails.label <- function(x, theta){
  if(theta %in% c("west", "east")) return(x$y) else
  yDetails(x$children[[1]], theta) 
}

lab1 <- labelGrob(0.1, 0.5, "start")
lab2 <- labelGrob(0.6, 0.75, "end")
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(lab1)
grid.draw(lab2)
grid.curve(grobX(lab1, "east"), grobY(lab1, "east"),
           grobX(lab2, "west"), grobY(lab2, "west"), 
           inflect = TRUE, curvature=0.1)
```

Comment: Very nice. The custom `(x|y)Details` methods are an esp. elegant touch!